# Access levels of variables/functions in restricted type

Tags: swift

Say we have a type `MyClass` which is restricted, e.g. to the module (`internal`) or to the file (`fileprivate`). It has variables and functions that should be available to anyone who can access the type itself. I could either:

1. Make them public. The restriction is already enforced at the type level, so it doesn't matter that the access level of the variables/functions is overly permissive. And if I ever want to use the type in another module or file, I only have to raise the access level of the type, and I don't have to go through all the variables/functions and raise their access level as well.
2. Or make the access level of each variable/function as restrictive as possible. I like this as a general philosophy, but is it advisable here?

**I want to know:**

1. Are there any conventions, best practices, or recommendations that favor either of the two approaches?
2. Did I correctly state the consequences of either approach?
3. Is there a third, possibly better way?

Comment: Agreed. The best answer is "do nothing." When there's a specific problem you're trying to address, then add access controls to address that problem.

Comment: I disagree. If you limit the places where a function or variable could be used, you improve your ability to reason about your code, which in turn makes changes easier.

Comment: @matt, it is true only if the type's access level is equal to or lower than the member's access level. If you have a public class with a function that has no specified access level, it is internal by default and cannot be used in another module, but the type itself can be. At least, that's my understanding of the Swift access levels.

Comment: @matt, I didn't mean to offend you. I just don't think what you proposed is a good solution.